# PL/SQL : statement ingored

Tags: oracle, plsql

WHEN I EXECUTE THIS PROCEDURE

```
create  procedure p2 is
         cursor c100 is select b.BNO,b.BNAME,b.PUBNAME,b.PRICE
        from book b,author a, bo_aut ba
        where b.BNO=ba.BNO
        and a.ANO=ba.ANO
        and a.ANAME='kanetkar';
   begin
        for x in c100
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(x.BNO||'     '||x.BNAME||'     '||x.PUBNAME||'      '||x.PRICE);
     end loop;
   end;
/
```

GOT THIS ERROR

> ERROR at line 10: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   1. create  procedure p2 is
>   2.          cursor c100 is select b.BNO,b.BNAME,b.PUBNAME,b.PRICE
>   3.         from book b,author a, bo_aut ba

Comment: Can you post your table schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error with your SQL statement (so the `select ...` part).

Without the schema we cannot tell the exact reason, but try to run the query itself and find out what the problem is.

Comment: thank you so much. yes u r right i had given wrong schema name in query i just corrected it and it ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

There must be an error with the query in your cursor. I have put together a basic example of an equivalent procedure with a working query:

```
create or replace procedure p2 is

   cursor c100 is 
      select 'a1' as BNO, 'b1' as BNAME, 'c1' as PUBNAME, 'd1' as PRICE
        from dual
      union 
      select 'a2' as BNO, 'b2' as BNAME, 'c2' as PUBNAME, 'd2' as PRICE
        from dual;

begin
   for x in c100 loop
      dbms_output.put_line(x.BNO||'     '||x.BNAME||'     '||x.PUBNAME||'      '||x.PRICE);
   end loop;
end;
```

From this I get the expected output:

```
a1     b1     c1      d1
a2     b2     c2      d2
```

I would suggest running your SQL separately to debug.